# How do I customize the name of an indirect has_many association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, has-many-through, has-many

In Rails, we have the `has_many` feature:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_sales
  has_many :states, through: :product_sales
end
```

Is there any way I can give a custom name to one of these `has_many`s?

For example: instead of accessing `states` from `Product` by using `@product.states`, I would like to access it using `@product.states_where_it_is_sold`.

Comment: Yes, there is definitely a way to do that. I believe you want to check out section 4.3.2.9 of the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference). And, perhaps, just `@product.states_where_sold`, but that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @jvillian, thank you for the reply :D. I tried like that: `has_many :states, through: :product_sales, source: :states_where_it_is_sold`, but it did not work =/

Comment: Try `source: :state` instead. `source` should refer to the `belongs_to :state` field on `ProductSale`.

Comment: Nevermind, I just did it using `has_many :states_where_it_is_sold, through: :product_sales, source: :state`. Could you please write an answer so I can set it as correct, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Do:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_sales
  has_many :states_where_sold, through: :product_sales, source: :state
end
```

Comment: Sweet! It works \o/. Thank you very much, @jvillian!